# Coffeescript Code not Deploying to Heroku Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm using Rails 4 and having a problem deploying javascript to production. We've been stuck on this for days and could use some help.

Here is our site:
https://triphappy.herokuapp.com/

Any javascript files that are access via CDN work fine, but any of the code in our .coffee files does not execute once deployed.

For example, in our file welcome.coffee, we have an alert as the first line of code. This works fine in our local environment, but does not work in production.

```
$ ->

  alert 'test';

  $('a[href^="#"]').on 'click.smoothscroll', (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    target = @hash
    $target = $(target)

    $('html, body').stop().animate {
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 500, 'swing', ->
      window.location.hash = target

  #Countdown JS
   `$(function(){
        $(".digits").countdown({
          image: "assets/digits.png",
          format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
          endTime: new Date(2016, 0, 1)
        });
    });`
```

After reading many threads here, it seems like it is an issue with our asset pipline. We've tried everything we could that we've read about, to no avail.

We've tried:

Gemfile
`gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`

Production.rb
`config.assets.compile = true`

We've tried precompiling, committing, then deploying:
`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

All help is appreciated. We're fairly new to rails and have no idea how to fix this.

**Update: Here is application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.countdown.js
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**Update 2: **

After looking at my compiled files in production, I can see the lines of code have been compiled into JS, they just don't appear to be executed.

From application-92ced....js (heroku generated name):

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    alert('test');
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click.smoothscroll', function(e) {
      var $target, target;
      e.preventDefault();
      target = this.hash;
      $target = $(target);
      return $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
      }, 500, 'swing', function() {
        return window.location.hash = target;
      });
    });
    return $(function(){
        $(".digits").countdown({
          image: "assets/digits.png",
          format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
          endTime: new Date(2016, 0, 1)
        });
    });;
  });
```

There is one javascript error on page load, from npm.js. We never touched this file and it has been happening since the beginning.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Comment: "do not work" is not a helpful description of the problem...

Comment: Edited my response to add more detail. It appears the code not being executed is all located in my coffee file. By "does not work", I mean does not execute. For example, the alert isn't being triggered.

Comment: Are files being generated by the compilation? Do they exist on the server after a deploy? Are the assets being requested? If so, are the requested files where they are expected to be? Are there js errors on teh page? http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Can't get onto the app?

Comment: can you add your manifest file(application.js), please?

Comment: @RichPeck - Sorry, was trying to fix my app and broke it for a little bit. It's up now.

Comment: @rob - Added manifest file to initial question. Thanks!